# compiler warning: local variable is redundant

Tags: java, debugging, warnings, local-variables

I am receiving a compiler warning that says `local variable 'newElement' is redundant`. How can I write the following code more efficiently to rid my code of this warning?

```
Element newElement = new Element(left,elements.next);
elements.next = newElement;
```

Comment: `elements.next = new Element(left,elements.next);` I'm not convinced that is an improvement though.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes having a redundant variable is desirable (perhaps for code clarity).  In these cases the warning can be suppressed.

```
@SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a list `a -> b -> c` and now you want to add `d` to it. What you have written tries to make `d` point to `d`.

This block

```
    Element newElement = new Element(left,elements.next);
    elements.next = newElement;
```

is equivalent to

```
    elements.next = new Element(left,elements.next);
```

which really doesn't make a bunch of sense.

If you are trying to make something like a linked list,

```
Element newElement = new Element(left,null);
elements.next = newElement;
```

Comment: @Doom3030 I think the solution would be relevant to you then